# Icon in shiny/ shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

My client wants me to create a `shinydashboard` that contains this icon:

[image]

Does anyone know of a similar icon

or anything in `shiny` / `shinydashboard` that allows me to put a number in the middle of a circle???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just about the icons, you will find it here:

https://fontawesome.com/icons/circle?style=regular

But if you want to show a number inside, you could do that with plain css.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Circle"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
          includeCSS("www/style.css"),
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         tags$div(id="insidediv", textOutput("slideroutput"))
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$slideroutput <- renderText({
        input$bins
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

CSS File:

```
#insidediv {
    background-color:#fff;
    border:4.5px solid grey;    
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    width:100px;
}

#slideroutput {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

[image]